# How not to block the UI while instantiating a lot of controls

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, xaml, task-parallel-library

There are lots of articles about how to keep the UI thread free in WPF. Mostly, using async-await to perform long operations in the background. But what can I do when the UI generation itself is heavy?

Say I have a view model that holds a list of items in a property called "Items" of type List, and a view that presents them using an ItemsControl that is bound to that list and generates ui for each item using a data template. I am reading information from the server and while I am getting the data, there is some sort of animated "Busy" indicator that is bound to a IsBusy property in the view model. All is well with that approach and it keeps the UI responsive.

Once the data had returned and the task is done, I am also generating the observable objects (ItemType) for each item in a background task (since no UI is bound to them yet, this is not a problem), and copy the information from the result that came from the server. Still - all nice and responsive.

The last step must happen in the UI thread. Once the List is ready, placing it inside the Items property yields a notification that causes the ItemsControl to start generating UI for each item, and this happens (and must happen) on the UI thread. Since this is a heavy task (there are not a LOT of items but each items has a pretty heavy UI template), the UI hangs and the busy indicator no longer animates.

My question is this: is there a way to keep the UI responsive while the items control is populating? This currently takes between 0.5 - 3 seconds and its too long a task for the UI to remain stuck.

EDIT:
Just to make it clear - this is not a question about Virtualization. I have no problem with the view taking long to create, I just want to find a way to keep to UI responsive while it is being created. I thought about perhaps drawing it while its hidden, or even collapses, but it does no change anything since the UI thread is still busy while doing that, and the busy animation still gets stuck, and the entire UI along with it.

Thanks

Comment: You do not use UI virtualization? Support for that is - albeit a little hidden - in WPF. That avoids generating the UI elements for items not visible, doing so on demand.

Comment: virtualization is not the issue here since there are not that many items and scrolling is not required. As I wrote - there are few items, but each has a pretty heavy data templete. I am looking for some way to draw the screen in the back (while its hidden or collapsed) and then show it once it's ready, but that also happens in the UI thread and it still affects the responsiveness

Comment: @KobiHari Why does it take so long to create the template for each item?  What is taking the majority of that time?

Comment: I don't know, but maybe you could generate the UI with two different 'UI-objects' and insert the one that takes so long into the main when finishes.

Comment: @servy, I don't know but its beyond my control. I am required to use a custom control that takes long time to be built.

Comment: @KobiHari Then you need to figure out how to prevent that custom control from taking so long to be built.  It likely should be offloading some non-UI work to a non-UI thread, possibly by accepting some already computed values before being constructed, or by yielding from its constructor quickly but taking some more time to finish updating the display.

Comment: @blacai That's what I am looking for, but the second UI object is still generated in the UI thread, so its still blocking the UI while it's doing that.

Comment: @KobiHari Then you need to fix that object so it doesn't do that.

Comment: Did you try with the dispatcher?

Comment: @servy, thanks but that's not going to work in this case. I am not bothered by that fact that it takes long time to build the ui for the items, I am just trying to keep the ui responsive while that happens.

Comment: @KobiHari Have you profiled your UI to see what takes them so long to generate a datatemplate?

Comment: @KobiHari And in order to do that you need to not have the object block the UI thread.

Comment: @yuval no, again, the question is not how to shorten the load time. I am specifically asking if there is a way to do it in a non-blocking way. Please take the fact that the data templates are heavy as a constraint.

Comment: @KobiHari have you thought about processing them in batches then?

Comment: @Yuval, perhaps you can add an answer and explain your solution?

Answer (score -1):

Yes. Don't draw all the items at once - only draw those you need to draw immediately. This is otherwise known as UI virtualisation.

Microsoft give a good example of how to implement virtualisation using a canvas at the following link: [Virtualized WPF Canvas](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jgoldb/archive/2008/03/08/performant-virtualized-wpf-canvas.aspx)

**Update after comment:**

If you hide the panel, the items are actually drawn on to the panel but are invisible. To stop the items appearing one by one, set the panel to `Visibility.Hidden` and then to `Visibility.Visible` once you've drawn the items. The panel appears blank and then is suddenly populated.

Comment: I am using virtualization. The items control uses a VistualizaingStackPanel and virtualization is enabled. As I said, the problem is not with the amount of items drawn (there are not so many) but each item has a heavy data template. To make the problem clearer - the UI that is *currently visible* takes too long to create. Thats why I am wondering if there is away to make it non blocking.